# How do you add custom text to the submit tag in a rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I want to customize the text in the `<%= f.submit %>` of my rails form.

If you I do `<%= f.submit "New object" %>` then it will say new object for both the new and edit actions. How can I make it so that there are two different custom messages for the new and edit actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like suppose you have `post` model then `@post.new_record?` or `f.object.new_record?` depending upon this conditionally you can update text

Comment: That's a good idea. I was just wondering if there was a clean one-line solution in Rails. If not, no biggy. Thanks for the suggestion.